# Sorting an array of objects in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort an `array` of `objects` with `ActionScript 3`.

The array is like this:

```
var arr:Array = new Array ();
arr.push ({name:"John", date:"20080324", message:"Hi"});
arr.push ({name:"Susan", date:"20090528", message:"hello"});
```

can I do something with `Array.sort(...)` method?

Comment: How do you want to sort the elements?

Comment: It doesn't matter, only looking for a method to sort arrays of objects, i could sort for date or name, the answer of Kenny is perfect, an it works perfectly

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do what? If you're trying to e.g. sort by name, then date, use [`Array.sortOn`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Array.html#sortOn%28%29).

```
arr.sortOn(['name', 'date'])
```

Answer (score 5):

Other than using `sortOn`, which will work for fields like strings and numbers, if you have other objects or more complex logic, you could pass a compare function to the [sort()](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Array.html#sort()) method.

Your compare function will be called by the sort function as many times as neccesary to sort your array. Each time, it will pass to your function two of the arrays' objects. Here, you determine how these two objects sort and tell that to the sort function by returning:

- a negative number: if the first
  object comes before the second one
- a positive number: if the second
  object comes before the first one
- 0: if both objects have the same sort
  order.